# Multiple cross reference table joins in linq

Tags: c#, linq, cross-reference

This has been bugging me for a while since I'm trying to come up with an optimized way of querying this.

So lets say I have 3 cross reference tables that share a common column, where that common column will do a final join on a main table that contains more info.

For example:

Let's say I have the following:

```
 Customers //properties: ID, Name, Address
 IEnumerable<CustomerSports>     // properties: CustomerID, SportsID
 IEnumerable<CustomerLocation>   // properties: CustomerID, LocationID
 IEnumerable<CustomerPets>       // properties: CustomerID, PetsID
```

So I can make queries such as:

Give me a list of customers that plays lacrosse, football, soccer (`CustomerSports`) and have dogs and cats (`CustomerPets`), that live in New York (`CustomerLocation`). The lookup tables can be nullable, so Customers could play sports, but have no pets.

Then when I get a list of customers, I'll join that common column (`CustomerID`) on the customer table to retrieve the ID, Name, and Address.

I was thinking about having the customer table join on each lookup, and then doing a union to fetch the list of customers, but I don't know if that is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: You want customers that have pets OR play sports (left outer join), or only customers that do/have all of those things? (you used the word AND in the question but the fact that you mention some customers can do one but not the other makes me think you meant OR).

Comment: Browse through here it might lead to some insights. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have setup your design correctly then each `Customer` should have a `Sports` collection, a `Pets` collection and a `Locations` (unless this last one is a one-to-one join?).

If those relationships are setup, then you can query as follows:

```
var sports = new string[] { "lacrosse", "football", "soccer" };
var pets = new string[] { "cat", "dog" };
var locations = new string[] { "new york" };
var sportyPetLoversInNewYors = db.Customers
    .Where(cust => sports.All(sport => cust.Sports.Any(custSport => custSport.Name == sport)))
    .Where(cust => pets.All(pet => cust.Pets.Any(custPet => custPet.Name == pet)))
    .Where(cust => locations.All(loc => cust.Locations.Any(custLoc => custLoc.Name = loc)))
    // could customise the select here to include sub-lists or whatever
    .Select();
```

This assumes that you only want people that have all 6 criteria. If you want people that like at least one of those sports, with at least one of those pets, and (assuming you used more than one location) are in at least one of those locations, the `Where` expression would change like the following

```
.Where(cust => cust.Sports.Any(custSport => sports.Contains(custSport.Name)))
```

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: I realized this is my true solution. I have more control over the filters than doing a join. When I tried the join, it'd do an inner for all tables. But the thing is, I need it where I'd filter based on 3 data sources, if there's any sports, any pets, OR any locations. If I did my join, and any of those are empty, it'd return an empty set.

Comment: This is much better than using JOIN CPU/Memory cost-wise, since it compiles into SQL that uses EXISTS (can check it with LINQpad for example)

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this, if i understood what you were after. Allows multiple sports, and multiple pets, or none.

```
        var contacts = from cust in customer
                       join sport in sports on cust.CustomerID equals sport.CustomerID into multisport from sport in multisport.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join loc in location on cust.CustomerID equals loc.CustomerID
                       join pet in pets on cust.CustomerID equals pet.CustomerID into multipet from pet in multipet.DefaultIfEmpty()

                       select new
                       {
                           cust.CustomerID,
                           multisport,
                           loc.LocationID,
                           multipet
                       };
```